# Recyclerview items become invisible when switching fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

After figuring out how to use a Recyclerview to display items, I've encountered a bug wherein the Recyclerview's items disappears when I switch between fragments.

**Solution: It turns out that the Main Activity Xml gets replaced by the fragment then when I come back it inflates a blank fragment. All I had to do was to create a different fragment for the Main Activity.**

Comment: do you use viewpager to switch between your fragments or not?

Comment: @masoudvali No, I don't use that. I use the navigation drawer

Comment: How are you switching between fragments. Can you show that code and a GIF of what you are currently experiencing ?

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil I use this: menufragment = mainmenu(). Is that switching or replacing? I am not too sure since I think its more on switching. If I made a mistake, just tell me. I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Whenever a fragment is recreated i loads default values into adapter so by default if your arraylist data is null it would make your recycler view empty  so to solve this make your arraylist data static

Comment: please add your main activity and fragments full code

Comment: @Mr.Patel What do you mean? If I make my arraylist data like this (var name: String? = null) it doesn't restore it?

Comment: can you add main activity xml file too

Comment: Yes exactly if arraylist is null then on recreation it will make your recycler view empty

Comment: To solve this put your arraylist into companion object

Comment: @masoudvali It is just a linear layout

Comment: @Mr.Patel I am not too familiar with companion objects. Can you put your answer in the answer area and not the comment area so I can approve your answer? Tysm :)

Comment: I would prefer to use a ViewModel + LiveData approach to share and update data between any fragments. Read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this go to your class where you're passing the arraylist of data to recyclerview adapter and simply put that arraylist into an companion object such that whenever it's recreated it would retain it's previous value
eg:
Put this inside your class:-

```
 fun loaddataintoarrlist(){
    //load your data into arraylist such that it's not empty
arrlist.add("abc")
    }

companion object{
//Your arraylist
var arrlist:Arraylist?=null
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but then it still doesn't work. What is wrong with this? import android.content.Context
import org.json.JSONArray
import java.io.File

class devices(
    var name: String,
    var text: String
) {
    fun loaddataintoarrlist(context: Context) {
        val file = File(context.filesDir, "devices")
        val contents = file.readText()
        val jsonArray = JSONArray(contents)
        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

Comment: val json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val name = json.getString("name")
            val text = json.getString("text")
            arrlist?.add(devices(name, text))
        }
    }

    companion object{
        //Your arraylist
        var arrlist:ArrayList<devices>?=null
    }
}
This is the extension of the code above

Comment: before doing arrlist.add() pass a if condition if(arrlist==null){arrlist=Arraylist()
and then do arrlist.add()
}

Comment: If you're still facing problem show me your full fragment class

Comment: It would be really helpful to debug if you can show your full code i.e all classes of activity and fragment

Comment: Okay your current code looks good can you show that xml file where you've used recyclerview? one more thing you're storing data into arraylist from loaddataintoarrlist method but where are you initializing the method?